# C# File.Exists returns false for the network drive file, but files appears after refresh

Tags: c#, windows, networking, samba, subnet

File.Exists method returns false for a network file, and I cannot see this file.
But it appears after refreshing this network folder.
Does somebody know how to fix it ? I have Windows 7 installed on the local machine and Samba on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite 'normal' behaviour for Samba with Windows.

If you add refresh = 1 to your smb.conf file and restart the service that should solve the problem.